# Run iOS 12.3.1 simulator on Xcode 10.1

Tags: xcode, macos, ios-simulator, ios12, xcode10.1

I have an older Mac Mini (mid 2011, 2.3GHz Intel Core i5). The latest os for this Mac is High Sierra (10.13.6) and latest Xcode is 10.1. I have iOS simulator 12.1 now within Xcode. But I would like to run simulator 12.3.1 (latest production). I was not able tu update the 12.1 to never version via the official setting (update button does nothing).

Is it possible to run newest simulator somehow? If not possible officially, is there a workaround to run iOS sim 12.3.1 on this old Mac?

Comment: You will not get happy with the simulator. I also used to have a 2011 MacBook Pro, but the simulator somehow requires Metal support by the GPU, so it was very laggy.

Comment: Well the iOS 12.1 simulator runs pretty good, I have 8 GB of RAM.

Comment: Did you try downloading Xcode 10.2.1 directly from https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?name=Xcode

Comment: Not yet, downloading it right now. I thought it would not install anyways, but I will try.

Comment: I installed  Xcode 10.2.1 manually (extracting .xip file). When i run the Xcode.app file, it tells me it wont run because it needs macOS 10.14.3 or later.

Comment: Xcode 10's simulators do not require Metal on the host.  They fall back to using OpenGL if Metal isn't present.  However, due to bugs in Intel's OpenGL Stack, we blacklisted HD3000 OpenGL, which means that on 2011  Macs, we end up using software GL, which consumes more CPU and also has its own set of bugs (most noticeable with the last frames of an animation).

Answer (score 1):

We do not support running the iOS 12.3 Simulator Runtime on High Sierra.  You might be able to get some of it to work (maybe well enough for you?) if you install the simruntime manually.  Copy it out of Xcode.app to /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes